# BackboneJs - Should model or Collection have knowledge of view

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, view, backbone.js, underscore.js

In one of the example i picked from SO answers here and many BackBoneJs examples i see that the initialize function knows which view the model is going to be rendered with. I don't know i am kind of biased now, is this a good practice or it depends on type of application being developed.

#### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas/Yqk5A/

#### Edited Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Yqk5A/187/

#### Code Reference

```
FriendList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.bind("add", function( model ){
            alert("hey");
            view.render( model );
        })
    }
});
```

Is the above a good practice or below

```
var friendslist = new FriendList;
var view = new FriendView({el: 'body'});
friendslist.bind("add", function( model ){
            alert("hey" + model.get("name"));
            view.render( model );
        })
```

in the edited fiddle collection is rendered by a view, and we also can use many more views to render the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the collection should know about the view that is used to render it.  I know in my projects, the same collection is render in multiple ways so that approach would deteriorate rapidly.

In general I pass the collection to the view that renders the collection and the view will listen to add/remove/update events of the collection to render the elements.  The collection view will have knowledge of the child view.

Check out the following link (3rd blog in a series) and in particular the `UpdatingCollectionView`.  This is the approach that I've found useful.

http://liquidmedia.ca/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/

Comment: exactly that's my exact questioning here, the model should not be tied to a view. I can use any view to render the model, so does `code#2` prove this or sticking with `code#1` is good?

Comment: Yes code#2 is better imho.  I was going another step and saying that if you're rendering a collection, I would create a view for the collection--in your case something like `FriendListView`.  The binding of the add event should be within the `FriendListView`.

Answer (score 2):

I am all for using events,
I myself don't want to move the bind's outside the model, I'd keep them there like the original example

```
var app = {};
app.evt = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);  // adding a global event aggregator 

FriendList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.bind("add", function( model ){
            alert("hey");
            app.evt.trigger('addfriend', model);
        })
    }
});

//further in your code you can bind to that event
app.evt.bind("addfriend", function(model){
    var view = new FriendView({el: 'body'});
    view.render(model);
});
```

however, i find the example a bit weird, creating a new view, with body as element, and rendering it with giving a model to the render function.  i'd find it more logic if the view is created with a model as attribute, and then rendering the content into the body. but thats another subject all together.

in short, i move creating the view outside, listening to an event being triggered, but the bind on the collection stays in the collection code. i find it more managable to keep all the collection code at the same place.

Comment: another point i wanted to ask is , collection are not mandate for holding models right? they aid in more defined ways to manage set of models with sugar functions

Comment: of course, you are not required to use collections, though in my opinion it's more than just sugar functions, they work well with views, for example rendering lists, or the events you can bind to, but in short, you pick the elements you want to use, backbone will in no way require you to use collections if you don't want to use them.